# Make a call from my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, phone-call, url-scheme

I have implemented the ability to make a call from clicking on a row of descriptive tableview of my hotel; I used the URL scheme by writing the following code in method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath ":

```
NSString *phoneNumber=element.phone;                                       
[NSString *phoneNumberScheme = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@ ", phoneNumber];
NSlog(phoneNumberScheme);                      
phoneNumberScheme = [phoneNumberScheme stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumberScheme]];
```

No error! With NSlog I verified that the number was read correctly, and so it is (indeed on console appears tel:1-408-555-5555). The problem is that nothing happens!!!

At this point (also based on something I read on the web) I have a doubt that I can't test this thing on simulator! Am I doing something wrong or can't I test this "URL scheme" on the simulator?!

Comment: You have a space at the end of `@"tel:%@ "`. `[@"tel:" stringByAppendingString:phoneNumber]` is also somewhat cleaner.

Comment: What is the difference between my and your syntax?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on seanny94's answer: the simulator doesn't support a lot of iOS's URL schemes, including those for the Phone, Maps, Youtube, and SMS apps. This is also the case for devices like the iPod touch and the iPad, which don't have phone capabilities; before using any URL scheme via `-openURL:`, you should check for support for that scheme using `-canOpenURL:`, which will return `YES` or `NO` depending on whether the current device supports the URL scheme you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You can't test a phone call (or any phone-based function, for that matter) in the Simulator. There is no support for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this useful code

Remove spaces for your code

```
NSString *trimmedString = [yourNumberString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Code for Call after confirmation

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:trimmedString];
```

Code for direct calling

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:trimmedString];
NSLog(@"Number : %@",phoneNumber);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```