# calling phone number within the app issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have the following code:

```
phoneNumber = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i));
NSString *phoneNumberURLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"tel://%@", phoneNumber];
            NSURL *phoneURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:phoneNumberURLString];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
```

However, the issue with this is that, sometimes a certain phone number doesn't get called: for example if phoneNumber is (520) 123-1232, then this doesn't call the phone. Any idea on how to standarize the phone number format such that this method works for all cases?

Comment: is it only that number you specified? which numbers don't get called?

Comment: Are your running in the simulator or on a device...look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282778/make-a-call-from-my-iphone-application?rq=1

Comment: It's not just that number I specified.. essentially all numbers that is the following +15208238172 worked.. however if it's something like (520) 082 8172 then it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the spaces in the number. A space is not a valid URL character. It must be encoded propery as `%20`.

Comment: I don't have the docs handy. Look in the NString docs for method with a name like `stringByAddingPercentEscapes`.