# What does mobile network code of 65535 mean with CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().subscriberCellularProvider?.mobileNetworkCode?

Tags: ios

I'm looking at some code somebody else has written which has no documentation, why is this code making a comparison with 65535?

```
class func canMakePhoneCall() -> Bool
{
    guard let URL = URL(string: "tel://") else {
        return false
    }

    let canOpenURL = UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL)
    if canOpenURL == false
    {
        return false
    }

    let mobileNetworkCode = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().subscriberCellularProvider?.mobileNetworkCode

    let isInvalidNetworkCode = mobileNetworkCode == nil
        || mobileNetworkCode?.characters.count == 0
        || mobileNetworkCode == "65535"

    return isInvalidNetworkCode == false
}
```

Comment: Well it's the maximum size of an unsigned smallint (2 byte) value, does that help? Maybe checking to see if the code is invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094928/detecting-whether-or-not-device-support-phone-calls), this could be an indication of removed SIM card, or in general inability to make a call at the moment.

Comment: I have PureTalk chip that is able to make calls&texts, and I get this 65538 in iOS 16 for the mobileNetworkCode.